# How to check-in changes to multiple branches in TFVC

Tags: merge, checkin, tfvc

I have a branch A and a branch B, A is parent of B.

Nowadays, each time a programmer chek-in to B, has to decide either merging that changeset to A or not (it depends on business requirements)

Is there a way to do this in a command line?

Either check-in to A and B at same time, or check-in to A and merge to B?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

These are always 2 separate actions. Code must be checked in before it can be merged. But of course you could create a little batch file that issues the consecutive commands required to merge right after the check-in.